# Could not find template

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, error-reporting

I tired more then hours,but i could not find the solutions for this issue. i have site with Joomla 3.4. i have move the files to my local system. config the data base and other things, but page show error below.

```
Error displaying the error page: Could not find template "".: Could not find template "".
```

My config of db

```
public $dbtype = 'mysql';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'root';
public $password = 'user15';
```

please tell me how can resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you access the backend? If so try logging in and changing the default template so it can display the actual error message. This error is saying that it cannot even display the error because the template can't be found.

Comment: Sorry, i cant logged in backend...

Comment: Have your '/tmp' and '/log' file paths changed since the move? Also have your permissions changed any?

Comment: Goto the `#__template_styles` table and change the default template to Beez3. See if the template displays then.

Comment: one more thing, i tried to install vermilion theme in 3.4 joomla,just white screen displayed and theme is not installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your original website worked fine, and your localhost copy don't work, it's probable that something went wrong in the restoration process. Either some files are missing, or the database is incorrectly restored.

Here's a couple of things you can try in order to fix your website:

- If possible, download the original website again. Use [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html) to make a backup, then download it and restore it to your localhost environment using [Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html). Akeeba Backup will include all your files AND your database in one single file, and also includes a restoration script that helps you set up your `configuration.php` file correctly.
- If that doesn't work, try unzipping the [full version of Joomla 3.4](http://www.joomla.org/download.html) into your existing Joomla directory, replacing any existing files. Then remove the `installation` folder.

Comment: Thank its working,the downloading backup is corrupted issue.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you solved it. Corrupt backup or wrong `.htaccess` configuration are among the most common reasons when a copy of a working site breaks.

Comment: yes,but my sql files are corrupted some of the table is not exact.

Answer (score 2):

For me this happened because I had not exported the database properly, that is there were no data just the shell of tables.

So just ensure that insert statements exist in your sql statements
and by the way.. it not good to post your passwords and usernames here

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this where it couldn't find the template `default` in spite of the template being exactly where it was supposed to be in the custom MVC component I was developing.

In my case it turned out to be because I was extending `JViewLegacy` and I had my own `__construct` function but I had forgotten to call `parent::__construct()` in there so the base view wasn't initialised and it didn't know it's own path.